using setjmp/longjmp to time-slice tasks using a timer on ESP32S3 bare-metal
I have implemented in C a round-robin scheduler that cycles through 3 tasks. I want to time-slice my tasks, meaning that when a task takes more than a pre-determined timeout value x, it is interrupted and the next task is started instead.
In the scheduler's loop, I save the context using setjmp() before launching a task
while(1) {
    int jump = setjmp(jmpbuf);
    if (jump == 1) {
        printf("TASK TOOK TOO LONG, SCHEDULING NEXT ONE INSTEAD.\n");
    } else {
        taskRun(sched->current);
    }
    sched->current = sched->current->next;
}

Using timer group 0 on the esp32s3, I set up an alarm which triggers an interrupt that has a handler my_isr, which resets the interrupt and alarm registers and performs a longjmp to the previously saved context.
void my_isr() {
    printf("Panic!\n");

    TIMG_INT_CLR_TIMERS_REG |= BIT(0);

    reset(); //this resets the registers in timer group 0 and reenables the alarm.

    longjmp(jmpbuf, 1);
}

The first time a task takes too long, the alarm is triggered and the interrupt is correctly thrown and the next task is scheduled. But further on when the alarm is triggered again (which I can see because the alarm bit does flip), the interrupt is never thrown.
In my case, I highly suspect that the longjmp is somehow responsible since when I modify my_isr to only call reset() and then return (which returns to the task it was executing before the ISR was called), it is indeed able to throw other subsequent interrupts. Though the origin of the problem might completely differ.
I have found no conclusive way to solve this problem, do you have any ideas as to how to resolve it? Please note that I have to use longjmp.

I dont have the hardware so I dont know, but i think since longjmp loads the execution context env saved by a previous call to setjmp, so it happens. if ur adamant about solving it like this i think u might have to dabble with assembly.

Avoid setjmp and longjmp whenever possible.  They are dangerous and difficult to use well.

I also advise against setjmp().  I recommend you instead try to make the 3 tasks re-entrant -- and each task minds its own time by watching the clock() in loops of execution. If time exceeded, function X makes a note of where it left off, and exits allowing next task/function (Y, Z) in line.  When this function X is revisited, it checks a flag for unfinished work, beginning where it left off.   Else, it begins a new task as designed.  This design assumes the 3 functions are called  in a loop. This may sound complex, but doesn't have to be.   And it is much more stable than longjmp().

Just to start with, int jump = setjmp(jmpbuf); violates the rule in C 2018 7.13.1.1 4 that says  setjmp will appear only in certain contexts, such as the entire controlling expression of a selection or iteration statement.

The C standard stipulates: An invocation of the setjmp macro shall appear only in one of the following contexts: • the entire controlling expression of a selection or iteration statement; • one operand of a relational or equality operator with the other operand an integer constant expression, with the resulting expression being the entire controlling expression of a selection or iteration statement; • the operand of a unary ! operator with the resulting expression being the entire controlling expression of a selection or iteration statement;

or • the entire expression of an expression statement (possibly cast to void).
I don't think your assignment meets that criterion.

So, after a bit of fiddling, I discovered that the issue was with the interrupt signal number that I was using. After having a look at the esp32s3's technical reference manual, I found out that interrupt signal 19 is level-triggered. By using interrupt signal 10 instead, which is edge-triggered, the program now behaves as expected.
I believe the problem lied in the difference between the aforementioned trigger modes. The first one will "hold the level till the CPUx handles the interrupts" whilst in the latter "CPUx responds to this kind of interrupts immediately".
As pointed out in the busybee's answer, the ISR never returns using longjmp, which causes the level to be indefinitely maintained by the interrupt source. By using edge-triggered interrupts, there is no need to hold the level, and therefore multiple subsequent interrupts can be thrown.

Beside the problems with setjmp()/longjmp() mentioned in the comments, your main error is this:

You create the "closure" in the main thread outside any interrupt service level.
You jump back to that location from the ISR, which cannot finish its interrupt service.
If the same interrupt is triggered again, it will not call the ISR, because its former service has not finished and it is still blocked.

This explains also, why your experiment without longjmp() works: The ISR finishes the interrupt service.
You might get away under specific conditions, where you know exactly what you are doing on the machine level, and with so many guards that the source will never be used outside these conditions. You need to dive into the machine room of your target for this. So the general rule is: Don't do this. It is not portable and will break earlier than you think.

Some of the restrictions listed in the Linux longjmp() man page are informative here, especially "After long jumping from the signal handler, the program does
not call any non-async-signal-safe functions and does not
return from the initial call to main()."  It's not even safe to return from main() when you do things like longjmp() out of async code such as signal handler - or ISR.

@AndrewHenle While such information is helpful, it is target specific. The OP uses a bare metal environment, there is no Linux.
